# Good APA 102, SK9822, WS2812B alternative?

Tags: led

I know it's an old question but many posts about the issue are several years old, so maybe the market has changed since, hence my question:

I'm designing a Raspberry Pi compatible device for a client similar to an already existing [device](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_4_Mic_Array_for_Raspberry_Pi/#resources), which uses APA102 SPI controlled LEDs. Ideally I want my client to have a "plug and play" experience, meaning when he plugs the PCB into RPi, most of the old functionality of the existing device would work immediately, without changing the software. All would be great if not for supply issues with APA102s... And most of other similar and compatible(?) LEDs for that matter. They are either no longer produced, or are available only from obscure suppliers.

I found [this](http://digikey.com/product-detail/en/american-bright-optoelectronics-corporation/BB-HBGR32L-3-TRB-8/2007-BB-HBGR32L-3-TRB-8DKR-ND/9817415) LED from American Bright Optoelectronics Corporation, which seems to be available on reels, which is great since the device is to be PnP assembled. I'm not sure if it is compatible with the older Chinese like APA102, SK9822, WS2812B in terms of control.

If anyone has worked with these or similar LEDs, and can share some experience it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Initially I didn't notice the line on the digikey listing saying that the utilized LED is indeed APA-102C. I don't know if the IC is the same or not however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to evaluate operational or mechanical equivalency of the various Smart LEDs is to read the manufacturer data sheets. That will lead you to a full understanding of any differences that may exist and then you can make a decision if those differences can be ignored or not in your application.

According to the data sheet for the APA-102C the manufacturer (APA Electronic Co LTD, Taiwan) indicates that they have a Worldwide Patent on their SmartLED. This will limit the number of sources for the APA-102C or direct copies of it for the duration of time those patents are valid. The manufacturer may decide to second source license another manufacturer to permit a wider availability of parts.

The datasheet for the BL-HBRG32L (American Bright OptoElectronics Corp, California USA) appears on a quick overview to be generally compatible with the APA-102C. Bright's web site has news announcements indicating that their Smart LED line was introduced in April 2019. It is unclear if they made their own LED driver chip design or if they are operating under license from APA.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. On the second look I see that digikey listing lists APA-102C as the utilized LED so I guess they do make them under license. I guess I was tired and didn't notice

Comment: There is no such thing as a worldwide patent; only patents enforceable in specific countries.  As it happens the web site for the company shows images, impressively for patents in 9 countries. http://neon-world.com/en/certificate.php That is a lot but not the world.